# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleting, specific-answer

I posted an answer to this question:

[What can a student do to respond to faculty/administration decisions based on current political events?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84511/dealing-with-department-head-rejecting-american-professors-in-response-to-immigr)

MY answer was based on logic and included a link to a website supporting my information. Moreover, at the time I am writing this, my answer was the most up-voted one (with 3 up votes). So why was it deleted?

Answer (score 3):

I deleted your answer, in response to a flag raised by a user. (It was flagged as "rude or abusive"; I did not agree that it was "rude or abusive" but I deleted it for another reason, see below.)

On Academia Stack Exchange, questions that ask "Help me change X's mind about Y", where X is someone in the context of academia and Y is not academia-specific, should address more than "Explain why Y is wrong". (If the question was basically "Explain why Y is wrong" it would not be specific to academia, and would therefore be closed.) The question and answers, in order to be on-topic here, must address the academic context.

In the context of this specific question, "Is it wrong for Kuwaiti institutions to reject American participants" is not on topic here, and that's the question your answer addresses. The question of what a *student* specifically can do to respond to faculty/administration's decisions based on political events may be on topic, but your answer does not address that.

(Given the understandable confusion, I have since edited the title of the question to focus on the aspect that is on-topic at Academia Stack Exchange - "What can a student do to respond to faculty/administration decisions based on current political events?" Hopefully future answers will not make the same mistake.)

For reference, here is the content of your answer that I deleted:

> You should just tell him that Kuwait has a permanent ban on Israeli passport holders (source: https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IL&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=KW&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C ) and explain to him that by his logic, all the world countries should ban the citizens of Kuwait.

Comment: But my answer did answer this question - what this student can do is explain to the professor using this logic why his decision should be overturned.

Comment: @GeneralJournal while I do agree with you, that answer would benefit from an explanation of _why_ that approach would work, given that it is likely to result in some hostility with the department head.

Comment: @enderland (Sorry, I can't resist; I'll take the bait) Ironically, OP's answer cannot be edited to include such an explanation (surely, if the moderator hadn't acted so swiftly to delete the answer, someone could've pointed out to OP how to improve their answer in the comments). All of this begs the question: why **delete** the answer, rather than leave a comment to OP about how they should make their answer more suitable for the site?

Comment: @MadJack The OP can edit the deleted answer to directly address the academic context, and then flag for undeletion.

Comment: But _why_ should OP have to do that?

Comment: Because answers worthy of deletion *should be deleted*. If and when it is fixed, it can be undeleted, but far too often, that doesn't happen, and it is better to have bad content hidden until fix than shown until we get tired of waiting. The content is low-quality and that is the fault of the user who created it, if they wish it to be neither low-quality nor deleted, they need to put the effort into fixing it by edits.

Comment: Interestingly, the accepted answer to this question suggested that mod should not delete bad content, but just downvote it http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/834/people-denying-the-situation-in-the-questions-instead-of-answering?rq=1

Comment: @qsp This answer seems to address a different class of cases, "incorrect and bad answers", as in "bad advice". I see how it makes sense to not delete bad answers, since the downvotes a bad answer attracts are useful information. This argument doesn't apply to off-topic answers.